# Get path of current script when executed through a symlink

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink

I have a utility consisting of a couple of directories with some bash scripts and supporting files that will be deployed to several machines,  possibly in a different directory on each machine. The scripts need to be able to reference paths relative to themselves, so I need to be able to get the path to the file that's currently being executed.

I am aware of the `dirname $0` idiom which works perfectly when my script is called directly. Unfortunately there is a desire to be able to create symlinks to these scripts from a totally different directory and still have the relative pathing logic work.

An example of the overall directory structure is as follows:

```
/
 |-usr/local/lib
 |  |-foo
 |  |  |-bin
 |  |  |  |-script.sh
 |  |  |-res
 |  |  |  |-resource_file.txt
 |-home/mike/bin
 |  |-link_to_script (symlink to /usr/local/lib/foo/bin/script.sh)
```

How can I reliably reference `/usr/local/lib/foo/res/resource_file.txt` from `script.sh` whether it is invoked by `/usr/local/lib/foo/bin/script.sh` or `~mike/bin/link_to_script`?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Try this as a general-purpose solution:

```bash
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
```

In the specific case of the following symlinks, you could also do this:

```bash
DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
```

Comment: Works perfectly and is way simpler than the stuff I was trying.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeDeck Enjoy. Note that I fixed some quoting issues since first posting ... you might use an option from the latest edit in the event that you have spaces or other wacky characters in your path sometime. Even if it doesn't matter for this project, you might copy the code from your own scripts down the road and having the best option matters then!

Comment: I should clarify, the second one works perfectly.  The first solution you gave does not work for symlinks on my system.

Comment: @MikeDeck: The first solution works for the typical case of having various directories symlinked as part of the path, but won't help if the final binary is a symlink. That's what the second one manages to take care of.

Comment: Doesn't work if the script file is `source`d (e.g `$ source ./sript.sh`)
This works for both cases: `DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" && pwd)"`

Comment: The symlink one doesn't work on BSD/Mac :/. You can fix it by using greadlink from brew unix tools... to make it work in both, you'll need to do a swap if on mac. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: Combined method working in a bash shell. `DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" || ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )`

Answer (score 11):

one line:

```
cd $(dirname $([ -L $0 ] && readlink -f $0 || echo $0))
```

Comment: One line answers are typically not the most helpful. Please consider expanding your answer to include explanation, links or documentation which further support your suggested solution.

Comment: actually, you don't need to do this, readlink version of the original answer works just fine if is no symlink involved at all

Answer (score 4):

`readlink -f` doesn't work for me, I've this mistake:

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
```

But this works fine:

```
DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink "$0")")"
echo $DIR
```

Comment: Then you are on a Mac and [this should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac).

Comment: Yes, I'm on MacOs @isaac, but I don't have any question. I posted the command which works on my side.

Answer (score 1):

`DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" || ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )`

- `BASH_SOURCE` works with `source ./script.sh` where `$0` does not
- `readlink` supports symlinks
- `||` alternatively when no symlink is found

Answer (score 0):

One small addition to the above script. The -P option to pwd follows symlinks

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"
```

Comment: This only work when the symlink is part of the directory structure. It does not work when the file itself is linked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on macOS) I had to use:

```
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$(readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")" && pwd)
```

This is because the symlink or the script behind can both be called by users. So in both cases the original files directory has to be resolved. It works as following:

- `readlink "$0"` tries to get the file behind the symlink
- if the script is no symlink `echo "$0"` prints the physical location of the script
- in both cases we have the scrips location which we get the directory name of using `dirname`
- then we `cd` into that directory and print the absolute path using `pwd`

If you aren't on macOS just add the `-f` parameter for `readlink`.