# Refer to a file under the same directory of a script found in $PATH

Tags: bash, path

I have a bash script file, which is put under some directory added to $PATH so that I can call the script from any directory.

There is another text file under the same directory as the script. I wonder how to refer to the text file in the script?

For example, if the script is just to output the content of the text file, `cat textfile` won't work, since when calling the script from a different directory, the text file is not found.

Comment: A related issue recently came up here: [Get path of current script when executed through a symlink](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17499)

Comment: This question answers how to get a bash script files path reliably, I added that to my path: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4774054/1695680

Answer (score 43, accepted):

These should work the same, as long as there are no symlinks (in the path  expansion or the script itself):

- `MYDIR="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"`
- `MYDIR="$(dirname "$(which "$0")")"`
- A two step version of any of the above:

  `MYSELF="$(realpath "$0")"`

  `MYDIR="${MYSELF%/*}"`

If there is a symlink on the way to your script, then `which` will provide an answer not including resolution of that link. If `realpath` is not installed by default on your system, [you can find it here](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/realpath).

**[EDIT]:** As it seems that `realpath` has no advantage over `readlink -f` [suggested by Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path/17802#17802), it is probably better to use the latter. My timing tests indicate it is actually faster.

Comment: No problem. By the way where does `realpath` come from on your system. (For others that don't have it you can use [`readlink -f`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path/17802#17802)

Comment: @Caleb Actually I thought it belonged to the set of standard GNU utilities (coreutils), but I can see now it is a [separate package](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/realpath).

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz `realpath` dates back from before `readlink -f` (and even `readlink`, IIRC) was in GNU coreutils (there were several similar tools around. `readlink -f` eventually became the de facto standard); `realpath` is only kept for compatibility with scripts that still use it.

Comment: Whats the advantage of `$(dirname "$(which "$0")")` over `$(dirname $0)` where the `which` is no longer present? Isn't it the same?

Comment: `readlink -f` does not seem to work on Mac OS X 10.11.6, but `realpath` works out of the box.

Comment: @UlfR the `which` is unnecessary if you call your script with a relative path, e.g. `./a-dir/my-script`, but it is required if you put your script somewhere on your `$PATH` and then called it from an unrelated directory... `my-script` would then be expanded to it's full path before passing to `dirname`.

Comment: Just to confuse matters even more: The man page for readlink suggests that realpath is the preferred command, and it seems realpath(1) is planned to be future POSIX: https://man.netbsd.org/realpath.1

Answer (score 19):

My systems do not have `realpath` as [suggested by rozcietrzewiacz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path/17721#17721).

You can accomplish this using the `readlink` command. The advantage of using this over parsing `which` or other solutions is that even if a part of the path or the filename executed was a symlink, you would be able to find the directory where the actual file was.

```
MYDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
```

Your text file could then be read into a variable like this:

```
TEXTFILE="$(<$MYDIR/textfile)"
```

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: I actually wasn't refering to just your `which` suggestion. The normal solution for this involves either just `dirname` or a combination of `cd` and `pwd` in a subshell. Readlink has the advantage here. `realpath` seems to pretty much be just a wrapper for `readlink -f` anyway.

Comment: I don't know how `realpath` is different from `readlink -f`. I can only see it gives me the same results (as opposed to `which`).

Comment: Keep in mind that `readlink -f` (from GNU coreutils) does NOT require the last element of the path to exist, `readlink -e` does, but isn't supported by `busybox readlink`, which mimics the behavior of `-e` in their `-f` option.

Answer (score 14):

`$0` in the script will be the full path to the script, and `dirname` will take a full path and give you just the directory, so you can do this to cat textfile:

```
$ cat "$(dirname -- "$0")/textfile"
```

Comment: While this seems to work without `realpath $0`, you are wrong in saying that "`$0` in the script will be the full path to the script".

Comment: @roz In what way?

Comment: `$0` is the command as it was run, which can be e.g. `../script.sh`.

Comment: So, actually `$(dirname "$0")` returns the **relative** path to the script, as part of the invoked command - not the absolute path. This can lead to problems in scripts that change directories while running.

Comment: @roz Ah, interesting. So I guess it wouldn't cause a problem here since he's calling something on the path by name, but it would break other things. Thanks

Comment: If it is a simple script, there probably won't be a problem. But if it grows overtime... Better always be on the safe side with full paths :)

Answer (score 5):

You can put this at the top of your script:

```
cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" || exit
```

> The BASH_SOURCE internal bash variable is actually an array of
>   pathnames. If you expand it as a simple string, e.g. "$BASH_SOURCE",
>   you'll get the first element, which is the pathname of the currently
>   executing function or script.

Source: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Answer (score 4):

I was trying these and realpath didn't work for me.  The solution I went with is:

```
SCRIPTDIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
```

Which has worked well so far. I would like to know if there are any potential issues with the approach.

Comment: Good, but does not follow symlinks. Try this:
`SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "$( readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} )")" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd)"`

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
#! /bin/sh -
dir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P) || exit
dosomethingwith "${dir%/}/some-file"
```

Which is POSIX and should work as long as the dirname of `$0` doesn't end in newline characters, is not `-` and `$CDPATH` is not set (and [possibly a few other corner cases](/a/119991) if the script was not looked-up in `$PATH`).

Answer (score 0):

I always use `which` to find the full path of an executable from the PATH. For instance:

`which python`

If you combine this with the `dirname` command then you get:

```
wp=`which python`
dn=`dirname $wp`
ls $dn
```