# How to get `pwd` in the shell script that was started by another shell script

Tags: shell-script, pwd

`startScript.sh` is in `/root/script/startScript.sh`

`script1.sh`is in `/root/script/test/script1.sh`

`script2.sh`  is in `/root/script/test/script2.sh`

`startScript.sh` looks like below

```
#!/bin/bash
#some code!
sh `pwd`/test/script1.sh 2>&1 &
sh `pwd`/test/script2.sh 2>&1 &
#some code
```

`script2.sh` and `script1.sh` look like below

```
#!/bin/bash
> `pwd`/process_ids.txt
while true;do
  echo "The Process: `ps`" >> `pwd`/process_ids.txt
  #some code to parse the process, etc. and echo it
done
```

Here is the thing is, the `process_ids.txt` file is creating in `/root/script`. But according to `scriptx.sh` the `pwd` is `/root/scripts/test/`. I displayed the `pwd` in `scriptx.sh`, it is showing `/root/script/`. How can I get the `pwd` of `scriptx.sh`?

Comment: You don't want the current working directory (which is what `pwd` returns) of the script, but the location of the script itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add `test/` to the path of the file you're trying to create, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
> `pwd`/test/process_ids.txt
while true;do
  echo "The Process: `ps`" >> `pwd`/test/process_ids.txt
  #some code to parse the process, etc. and echo it
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to pass it as a parameter to scripts 1 and 2. So, modify `scriptx.sh` to (by the way, use `$PWD`, there's no reason to run an external command):

```
#!/bin/bash
#some code!
sh "$PWD"/test/script1.sh "$PWD" 2>&1 &
sh "$PWD"/test/script2.sh "$PWD" 2>&1 &
#some code
```

And `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"
> "$dir"/process_ids.txt
while true;do
  echo "The Process: `ps`" >> "$dir"/process_ids.txt
  #some code to parse the process, etc. and echo it
done
```

---

The more complex approach is to get the PWD of the parent script from the `/proc` filesystem. Since `scriptx.sh` is launching the others, they will have access to `scriptx.sh`'s PID in the `$PPID` variable. In Linux, each running process has a link to its current working directory at `/proc/PID/cwd`. Therefore, you could leave `scriptx.sh` unchanged and modify the others to:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$(readlink -f /proc/$PPID/cwd)"
> "$dir"/process_ids.txt
while true;do
  echo "The Process: `ps`" >> "$dir"/process_ids.txt
  #some code to parse the process, etc. and echo it
done
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, in `scriptx.sh`, the $1 has value `/root/script`...still the script is creating the the file in `/root/script`. We can send the argument as "``pwd``/test" in `startScript.sh` to `scriptx.sh`. But I don't want to do like that!...Is there any other way?

Comment: @Veerendra with my first suggestion, there is no `$1` in `scriptx.sh`. That's only in `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`. Passing `$PWD` to the daughter scripts is really is the simplest way. Still, see update for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to *get* or *pass* anybody anything. that's already done. the current working directory of a forked process is the current working directory of the parent process. so, unless those scripts are changing their current directory, and if they are it is either intended behavior or something you should stop them doing with an edit, then the current working directory is the same for everybody. but if there *were* a difference for some reason, then the output of...

```
`pwd`
```

...would be just as problematic and for exactly the same reasons, and so could not be considered as any indication one way or the other.

still, if you did want to check these things for another process, and you had the other process's PID - as you do for `script2.sh` in the shell parameter `$!` and which you can get for the other with `jobs -p`, then, on a linux system, you could do:

```
cd -P /proc/"$!"/cwd;pwd;cd -
```

...which will first change to the last backgrounded process's current working directory, then print it, then change back to the current shell's previous current working directory, and print it.