# Autostart application on login

Tags: debian, gnome3

I want to start `gui-java` application on startup.
So I tried to use

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

with my .desktop

```
debian@debian:~$ cat /etc/xdg/autostart/alclient.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ALClient
GenericName=ALClientt
Comment=ALClient
Exec=/home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/bin/client.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

and *cat* of *client.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
OPTIONS=
if [ -f client.l4j.ini ] ; then
    OPTIONS=$(grep -v '^#' client.l4j.ini | tr -d "\r" | tr "\n" " ")
fi
java $OPTIONS -jar client.jar
```

But when I restart my computer the application does not start.

I determnate two problems:

1. When I try to start app from `~/`

   ```
   debian@debian:~$ sh /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/bin/client.sh
   Error: Unable to access jarfile client.jar
   ```

   But when I start from its own directory then all is ok.

   ```
   debian@debian:~/my/app/2.4.93/client/bin$ sh /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/bin/client.sh
   Dec 20, 2015 9:25:12 PM checkJVMVersion
   WARNING: Run only with jre 1.8
   ...
   ```
2. My app set some default directory for its own.

   ```
   Home Directory          = /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client
   Data Directory          = /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/data
   Logs Directory          = /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/logs
   Config Directory        = /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/conf
   Locale Directory        = /home/debian/my/app/2.4.93/client/locale
   ```

I'm afraid that app will use other directory rather than define if start from /`etc/xdg/autostart/`

How I should correct setup autostart after login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your existing setup as described in your question, modify `client.sh` like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTIONS=

this_dir="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"

if [ -f "$this_dir/client.l4j.ini" ] ; then
    OPTIONS=$(grep -v '^#' "$this_dir/client.l4j.ini" | tr -d "\r" | tr "\n" " ")
fi

java $OPTIONS -jar "$this_dir/client.jar"
```

Save, then, restart your computer, see if it now starts up.

### Explanation

- `/etc/xdg/autostart` desktop file looks fine, so more likely the script it runs, `client.sh`, is the source of the problem
- the script `client.sh` that you posted had an extra backslash: `\#!/bin/sh`, but normally it is just `#!/bin/bash` to specify bash, or in your case `#!/bin/sh` is fine and let your system decides what `sh` should run, bash or otherwise.
- you said `client.sh` fails to work when run elsewhere but works when called from same directory containing `client.sh`, plus I see `client.sh` makes references to file names directly with no other code clarifying paths, which all suggests path problems
- referencing file names directly like that works only when current working directory contains those files, so to deal with uses when you are not running `client.sh` in the containing directory, we need to add extra code to help the script determine the full path
- `this_dir="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"` is based on [Bash - refer to a file under the same directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path) where `$0` is the full path to `client.sh`, `realpath` resolves in case there are sym link issues, and `dirname` just then obtains the path except for `client.sh`, thus obtaining the containing directory, saving it `$this_dir`
- `$this_dir/client.l4j.ini`: containing directory +file, so script can properly find `client.l4j.ini`
- `$this_dir/client.jar`: containing directory +file, so script can properly find `client.jar`

So, now that the script can properly find all the files necessary to run, and as long as you you restart to make it effective, it should now run.

Comment: **\** in **#!/bin/sh** just typo. Thanks for reply I'll try it. There is another way to resolve my problem - property **Path** for my **.desktop** [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)

Comment: Nice find! Hope that works for you, it would be a much quicker fix than my answer.