# Run shell command exectly one time at login

Tags: startup, xmodmap, .desktop, autostart

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and trying swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> using `xmodmap`. But failed to find a way of doing that automatically: `.[X|x]modmap[rc]` and `.config/autostart` didn't work. What other ways are there? Could it be possible throgh `systemd`?

**SHORT**:
Desktop entry in `.config/autostart` or `/etc/xdg/autostart`. `Exec` is not a full-fledged shell command, so `sh -c` might be required

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sh -c "xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc"
```

Comment: I think you want the command to run **when gdm starts** (so is technically not part of the boot process).

Comment: @RonJohn I would be grateful if you could write and answer about how to do it)

Comment: Sadly, I don't know how.  Hopefully though this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Comments are intended to be helpful: to help you improve the question / answer. So don't expect them to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ubuntu switched back from Unity to Gnome in version 17.10, you should be able to use the [Gnome autostart mechanism](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/autostart-applications.html.en) (if it is sufficient that the shell command is launched on login).

To do so:

- you will need `sudo` privileges
- create a shell script that runs the necessary command (say `switch_ctrl_capslock.sh`) and place it in `/usr/local/bin`
- create a `.desktop` file `/etc/xdg/autostart/switch_ctrl_capslock.desktop` with (more or less) the following content:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=/usr/local/bin/switch_ctrl_capslock.sh
  ```

If everything is setup correctly, the script should be run once when the user logs into Gnome.

For further reading, have a look at

- [Autostart application on login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250574/autostart-application-on-login)
- [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: How would this be used to swap the keys **before** login?  (Not that I know why you'd use the `Ctrl` key at the gdm login screen, but there might be something I don't know about.)

Comment: @RonJohn That is a little more involved. One problem is that the desktop environment/window manager often uses input methods that supersede the "raw" input interpretation (as can be found on the virtual consoles e.g.), but since they are run by the user logging in, doing that before login may prove to be ineffective. The solution would probably depend on the exact circumstances (graphics server, desktop manager, window manager).

Comment: Yep, desktop entry is the way to go. I've created one in `.config/autostart`. I've tried it before, but it failed because `Exec` is not a full-fledged shell command and don't expand tildes, variables and substitutions

Answer (score 2):

The `systemd`-way:

**Upon login**

```
[Unit]
Description=Change keyboard layout AFTER LOGIN TO GUI session
After=graphical.target

[Service]
#execute once only
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xmodmap home/<user>/.xmodmaprc

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

To be put under `~/.config/systemd/user/xmodmap.service` (note do NOT replace user with your username!).

To enable the service to be autoloaded:

```
systemctl --user enable xmodmap.service
```

To start it the first time without need for a relogin;

```
 systemctl --user start xmodmap.service
```

**Running it as soon as `gdm` is up**

Same file as above, but rather place it at `/etc/systemd/system/xmodmap.service` and add the following line to the `[Unit]` section to be save:

```
 After=display-manager.service
```

As root (or via sudo):

```
systemctl enable xmodmap.service
```

Of course it will then affect all users.