# Obtain script current directory (so that I can do include files without relative paths and run the script from everywhere)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following problem, my shell script contain something like:

```
mydir=''

# config load
source $mydir/config.sh

.... execute various commands
```

My script is placed in my user dir.. let's say `/home/bob/script.sh`

If I'm inside the `/home/bob` dir and run `./script.sh` everything works fine.

If I'm outside and want to use the absolute path `/home/bob/script.sh` the config.sh file is not recalled properly.

What value should i assign to `$mydir` in order to make the script runnable from every path without struggle?

```
mydir=$(which command?)
```

PS: as bonus please also provide an alternative if the script dir is inside the $PATH

Comment: I don't see how the script you've posted can ever work. Providing real (minimal) code illustrating your issue is helpful.

Comment: `mydir='/home/bob/'` If the script inside the $PATH you can call it just by name `source config.sh`

Comment: There's a highly-upvoted duplicate over on Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange really needs a mechanism for marking this cross-site!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refer to a file under the same directory of a script found in $PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `$0` variable contains the script's path:

```
$ cat ~/bin/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $0

$ ./bin/foo.sh
./bin/foo.sh

$ foo.sh
/home/terdon/bin/foo.sh

$ cd ~/bin
$ foo.sh
./foo.sh
```

As you can see, the output depends on the way it was called, but it always returns the path to the script relative to the way the script was executed. You can, therefore, do:

```bash
## Set mydir to the directory containing the script
## The ${var%pattern} format will remove the shortest match of
## pattern from the end of the string. Here, it will remove the
## script's name,. leaving only the directory. 
mydir="${0%/*}"

# config load
source "$mydir"/config.sh
```

If the directory is in your `$PATH`, things are even simpler. You can just run `source config.sh`. By default, `source` will look for files in directories in `$PATH` and will source the first one it finds:

```
$ help source
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
when FILENAME is executed.
```

If you are sure your `config.sh` is unique or, at least, that it is the first one found in `$PATH`, you can source it directly. However, I suggest you don't do this and stick to the first method instead. You never know when another `config.sh` might be in your `$PATH`.

Comment: `~/bin/foo.sh` it is just *tilde expansion* , not a full path. Use `readlink -e $0` instead

Comment: @Costas I edited to clarify that `$0` is not always the absolute path. It is always the path to the script though, so this approach should work. Can you think of cases that would break it?

Comment: This didn't work for me when the script is called via `sh nameofscript.sh`, the name of the script is matched so `mydir='nameofscript.sh'`.

Comment: @iain no, of course it won't work then, but that's a different issue. The question here was about executing the script by name. If you pass the script without a path as an argument to `sh`, then it's a totally different situation since `$0` will not contain the path. It will work as expected if you use `sh ./nameofscript.sh` or `sh /path/to/nameofscript.sh`. If you need it to work specifically for when you call it with just the name and nothing else, please ask a new question.

Comment: I didn't say the answer was wrong with regards to the question but that it didn't work *given a different way of calling it*, one which is *normal* and *valid*, but more importantly, it's a *helpful* piece of information to add to an answer via comment. "of course" is not something I'd consider a valid response on a question and answer site, its whole reason for being is ignorance, but thanks for your hard work on the site, I managed to get what I wanted from another answer.

Comment: @iain I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be dismissive (but on re-reading my comment I do see how it could have come across that way; my bad, I shouldn't answer comments before coffee). My suggestion to ask a new question was honestly offered. That's the best way to get the information you need and we try to avoid having conversations in the comments. Also, since I personally _never_ call a script with `shellName scriptName` but always use [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) instead, I admit I consider this a bit of an edge case. But that's my hangup.

Comment: @terdon Thank you, that's a very gracious apology, and my own comment history shows I fully understand the need for helpful coffee at times! :) My own apologies for misreading what you clearly didn't intend. Have a good day.

Answer (score 12):

This method is **only** useful in a **bash script**.

**Use:**

```
mydir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" > /dev/null && pwd )"
```

**How it works:**

`BASH_SOURCE` is an array variable whose members are the source filenames where the corresponding shell function names in the `FUNCNAME` array variable are defined.

So, with:

```
cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
```

you move to the directory where the script is placed.

Then, the output of `cd` is sent to `/dev/null`, because sometimes, it prints something to STDOUT. E.g., if your `$CDPATH` has `.`

And finally, it executes:

```
pwd
```

which gets the current location.

**Source**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: never hurts to explain a little bit about how your solution works. I know the Q is tagged bash, but the use of BASH_SOURCE does make this A bash-specific. There were other concerns brought up in the comment section of that SO answer as well that would be good to mention.

Answer (score 9):

Found the solution:

```
mydir=$(dirname "$0")
```

With this the script can be invoked from everywhere without throubles.

Comment: not if it is a symlink. This one is the most reliable I have found: `current_dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to this **tested** and verified with **shellcheck** solution:

```
mydir="$(dirname "${0}")"
source "${mydir}"/config.sh
printf "read value of config_var is %s\n" "${config_var}"
```

The test:

```
$ ls 
script.sh
config.sh
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash --
mydir="$(dirname "${0}")"
source "${mydir}"/config.sh

printf "read value of config_var is %s\n" "${config_var}"

$ cat config.sh
config_var=super_value

$ mkdir "$(printf "\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37\40\41\42\43\44\45\46\47testdir" "")"
$ mv *.sh *testdir
$ *testdir/script.sh
read value of config_var is super_value
```