# Matlab application command alias creation error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, alias, bashrc, launcher

I had installed MATLAB 2017b in my Ubuntu 18.04 PC and am able to execute it as :

```
sudo /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab -desktop
```

I intend to install another version sometime in the future as well.

I'm trying to create a command style terminal launcher `matlab2017b` (like how other applications like `gedit`, for example, can be executed) as:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab /usr/local/sbin/matlab2017b
```

which gives the error:

```
/usr/local/sbin/matlab2017b: 454: .: Can't open /usr/local/bin/util/arch.sh
```

Tried creating a bash alias too in `~/.bashrc` as:

```
alias matlab2017b='/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab'
```

It gives the same error as above too.

What is going wrong here? Shouldn't placing the executable in any of the paths inside $PATH be enough? And how to execute it in terminal by running just `matlab2017b`?

Comment: The script probably uses its location as a reference for where the MATLAB files are located. Have you tried a symlink? `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab /usr/local/sbin/matlab2017b`?

Comment: @muru That did it! Could you explain in a post below as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matlab` script likely tries to find the Matlab directory by looking up the location of the script (see, for example, [Get path of current script when executed through a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17499/70524)). This will fail if you copy the script to another location, but the popular solutions support symlinks, so you can try with a symlink instead:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab /usr/local/sbin/matlab2017b
```

Comment: I am unable to use `matlab2017b` in launcher `.desktop` file to execute from gnome. Why can't I do that? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit please post a new question about that. Also include the contents of the `.desktop` file you created.