# Sourcing file in dash with . file gives "not found" error

Tags: shell-script, dash

I'm trying to source (bash-parlance) a file in dash using `. file` as specified by the man page:

> ```
>  . file
>         The commands in the specified file are read and executed by the
>         shell.
> ```

But I get an error even though the file *is there*:

```
$ ls
defaults.sh  run.sh
$ cat run.sh 
#!/bin/sh

. defaults.sh

echo "VAR: $VAR"
$ cat defaults.sh 
VAR=abc
$ bash run.sh 
VAR: abc
$ dash run.sh 
run.sh: 3: .: defaults.sh: not found
```

The same thing happens when I try `. defaults.sh` in an interactive dash.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some shells, you need to put `./` or an absolute path in front:

```
. ./defaults.sh
```

Note, that you might want to add the [absolute path of the `run.sh` script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17499/get-path-of-current-script-when-executed-through-a-symlink), otherwise `defaults.sh` will be sourced from the user's location:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
. "$SCRIPT_DIR"/defaults.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to add $PWD to your PATH if running "dash run.sh" from the directory where the run.sh and defaults.sh file exists.

In my test I saw these results:

```
# dash run.sh
run.sh: 3: .: defaults.sh: not found
```

I then took this step:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
```

Results after added $PWD to the PATH:

```
# dash run.sh
VAR: abc
```

Comment: Changing `PATH` to `source` a file is not a very good idea I think but might be a last resort if you have a script you cannot change.

Comment: @pLumo  Thnak you for that information. I will keep that information and the solution you provided in my knowledge base as I'm sure I'll see this problem again soon.